# New model using signals

Tags: django

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

Is it possible to have new model using signals .
For example if i save  above model it must give me below model.

```
def create_customer(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    class Newname(models.Model):
        customername = models.CharField(max_length=100)


signals.post_save.connect(receiver=create_customer, sender=Customer)
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to have the model `Newname` defined within the `create_customer` function?

Comment: bro it is just rough example i have given actually  i am creating accounts management app so the requirement is he need new small apps inside main app .

Comment: It is just an example not real models.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def create_customer(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    Newname.objects.create(customername=instance.name)
```

This creates a `Newname` object and saves it to the database. The `instance` in this case would be the `Customer` object that you just saved.

Comment: name 'Newname' is not defined
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/budgetapp/customer/3/change/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value: 
name 'Newname' is not defined             getting this error

Comment: Have you included it in your models.py?